# How to verify that user entered empty string? in PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I need to know how to verify that the user entered empty string in a sentence if in a string with multiple spaces in blank

Example

```
  "                         "
```

if user entered a emṕty string, the program must show an alert as this

```
echo "The username must not be empty";
```

Comment: PHP is server side, JavScript/jQuery is client side. You're mixing the two, it'd be easier to just do this in jQuery OR PHP depending on your needs

Comment: "alert" is a js function....

Comment: if you want to stop or validate form submission, you can prevent it with js, like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-to-stop-form-submission

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use trim to remove whitespace from a var...

```
$name = trim($_GET['name']);

if ($name == '') //empty
```

Comment: Out of interest, what's the difference between this and `!$name`?

Comment: @AndyHolmes with PHP being loosely typed; nothing really. `!$name` is equivalent to `$name == false` which is equivalent to `$name == ''` ... it would only make a difference with strict evaluation `===`; you do have to be a little careful though as `0 == false` but `'0' == true` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if (strlen(trim($yourString)) == 0) {
    // Do something
}
```

If the length of the string is 0 after the spaces are trimmed/removed.